# How to test angular directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running to an issue for the unit test

I have something like

```
describe('test controller', function () {
    var =$compile, scope, rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
       $compile   = _$compile_;
        rootScope   = _$rootScope_;
        scope        = _$rootScope_.$new();
    }));

    describe('test', function() {
        beforeEach(function () {
            scope.toys = ['toy1', 'toy2'];            
        });
        it('should test directive' , function() {
            var element = $compile('<button type="button"  show-item>See all</button>')($rootScope);
            element.triggerHandler('click');
            $rootScope.$digest();
        });
    });
});
```

html

```
   <button type="button"  show-item>See all</button>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('showItem', 
function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {                
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                var l = scope.toys.length;
                //other codes
            });
     }
});
```

I am getting `undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.toys.length')` when I run the unit test.

I am not sure what went wrong as I already specify `scope.toys` inside beforeEach function. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are compiling with `$rootScope` which does not have the property `toys` in it. Instead use already set `scope` variable which has `toys` property.

```
  var element = $compile('<button type="button"  show-item>See all</button>')(scope);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qt72dI?p=preview)**